# Handle callback for wrapper class

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a wrapper class for managing singular connection for a chat.
When a message received first `ConnectionManager` handle it as wrapper and then callback to outside of class. Is there any solution to doing this?

I use singleton pattern for connection manager.

```
let _instance = null;
class ConnectionManager{
  static _hubConnection;
  static _proxy;

  constructor(hubUrl) {
    this._hubConnection = signalr.hubConnection(hubUrl);
    this._hubConnection.logging = true;
  }

  static getInstance(){
    if(_instance == null)
      _instance = new ConnectionManager(GLOBALS.HUB_URL);

    return _instance;
  }

  createHubProxy(){
    this._proxy = this._hubConnection.createHubProxy('Hub');

    this._proxy.on('addNewMessage', (message, fileUrl) => {
      console.log(message.Body);

      if(onReceivedNewMessage)// ---> Where is right place to define?
        onReceivedNewMessage(message);
    });
  }

  getHubConnection(){
    if(this._hubConnection)
      return this._hubConnection;

    return null;
  }

  getHubProxy(){
    if(this._proxy)
      return this._proxy;

    return null;
  }


}

module.exports = ConnectionManager;
```

and then use out side of class:

```
ConnectionManager.getInstance().onReceivedNewMessage( message => {
  console.log(message);
});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let _instance = null;
class ConnectionManager{
  static _hubConnection;
  static _proxy;

  constructor(hubUrl) {
    this._hubConnection = signalr.hubConnection(hubUrl);
    this._hubConnection.logging = true;
    this.createHubProxy();
  }

  static getInstance(){
    if(_instance == null)
      _instance = new ConnectionManager(GLOBALS.HUB_URL);

    return _instance;
  }

  onReceiveMessage(callback) {
      if(this._proxy) {
          this._proxy.on('addNewMessage', callback);
      }
  }

  createHubProxy(){
    this._proxy = this._hubConnection.createHubProxy('Hub');
  }

  getHubConnection(){
    if(this._hubConnection)
      return this._hubConnection;

    return null;
  }

  getHubProxy(){
    if(this._proxy)
      return this._proxy;

    return null;
  }


}

module.exports = ConnectionManager;
```

Comment: Thank you so mush, but the proxy object register all callbacks in constructor and before connect, is there any way to handle callback in createHunProxy inside .on() method?